# let docker bridge connect vlan interface

Tags: docker

Pre-Requisites:

```
sudo ip link add link eth0 name eth0.100 type vlan id 101
```

problem:

```
I want to start openvpn with docker in container, this step is easy:
sudo docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -p 1194:1194/udp --privileged -e DEBUG=1 kylemanna/openvpn
Then I need to let container can continue route package to eth0.100, after openvpn recieved remote client data.
There is my idea about it, but not working all.
```

1:
First create bridge:

```
docker network create bridge vpn_bridge
Then start container with vpn_bridge
sudo docker run --net=vpn_bridge  -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -p 1194:1194/udp --privileged -e DEBUG=1 kylemanna/openvpn
Finally, I find can't join the vlan interface to the vpn_bridge
```

2:

```
Use macvlan:
sudo docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.100.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.100.1  \
    -o parent=eth0.1000 pub_net
Then start container with pub_net:
sudo docker run --net=vpn_bridge  -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn -p 1194:1194/udp --privileged -e DEBUG=1 kylemanna/openvpn
Although container join vlan, but I found can't connect the container's openvpn server even in local host.
```

Is there anybody can give me more good way (ps: I already use traditional way solve it that use linux's default bridge)